# How to deploy web app from bitbucket

Tags: amazon-ec2, tomcat7, vaadin, bitbucket

I have a Vaadin web application in Bitbucket and I want to deploy the WAR file to my Tomcat 7 server in an Amazon EC2 instance.

How do I do this?

Comment: Did you manage to move the WAR file to the server? Is Tomcat running correctly? Can you access it from the browser in your PC?

Comment: Thanks @arturhoo!!...I can do it manually without problem, so far I export the WAR file from Eclipse and just upload it to the tomcat7/webapps/ folder... this is fine when on development stage and alone, but now I'm going to production stage and I will be coding with more people, that is why I'm implementing bitbuckets, and I also want to have the latest version of the app on the server and working...

Comment: I believe you're mixing two different stages in the software development and release cycle. Bitbucket is a place where you can collaborate with other people while developing your application. You can still retain control of the deployment to the production server and do it manually whenever the app is stable. Moreover, you might also be interested in  Continuous Deployment, where successful changes to the code are automatically deployed to the server [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/) and [GitLab CI](https://ci.gitlab.com) are good places to start looking at.